# MySQL JOIN with SUM

Tags: mysql, join

This question probably has been asked a lot of times, therefore, please, excuse me for duplicates, but I just couldn't seem to find something like this nor could I manage to build something similar to what I want to achieve.

For example, lets say, I have the following table structure:

```
//tasks
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   |  P  |  None   |  AI   |
| user  | int(11)      | NO   |     |  None   |       |
| data  | varchar(200) | NO   |     |  None   |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

//votes
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   |  P  |         |  AI   |
| user  | int(11)      | NO   |     |         |       |
| item  | int(11)      | NO   |     |         |       |
| up    | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| down  | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

With the following data:

```
//tasks
+----+------+------------+
| id | user |    data    |
+----+------+------------+
| 1  |  1   | something  |
| 2  |  2   | lorem ip   |
| 3  |  1   |   biggy    |
+----+------+------------+

//votes
+----+------+------+----+------+
| id | user | item | up | down |
+----+------+------+----+------+
| 1  |  8   |  1   | 1  |  0   |
| 2  |  4   |  1   | 1  |  0   |
| 3  |  2   |  1   | 0  |  1   |
| 4  |  2   |  2   | 1  |  0   |
| 5  |  1   |  2   | 1  |  0   |
+----+------+------+----+------+
```

I want to do something similar to:

```
   SELECT r.* FROM `tasks` WHERE `user` = '1' r
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(t.up) AS up,
                  SUM(t.down) AS down
             FROM `votes` t
            WHERE t.item = r.id) r ON r.id = t.item
```

And yes, that's my query so far, but it doesn't work, and I have no idea how to correct that.

Basicly, I want to:

1. Select *everything* from table *tasks* where `user` is "x"
2. Join each row from *tasks* (selected at step 1) with *sum of `up`*, *sum of `down`* from table *votes* where `item` is equal to `id` from *tasks*

And that should produce something like (ie. `user` = 1):

```
+----+------+------------+----+------+
| id | user |    data    | up | down |
+----+------+------------+----+------+
| 1  |  1   | something  | 3  |  1   |
| 3  |  1   |   biggy    | 0  |  0   |
+----+------+------------+----+------+
```

Well, I hope you guys understand and can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause needs to go below joins, and aliases should be declared using `AS`. This is a (syntactically) corrected version of your query:

```
   SELECT r.*
     FROM `tasks`
LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT SUM(t.up) AS up,
                    SUM(t.down) AS down
               FROM `votes` AS t
              WHERE t.item = r.id
          ) AS r
       ON r.id = t.item
    WHERE `user` = '1'
```

This is how i would do it (untested):

```
   SELECT `tasks`.`id`,
          `tasks`.`user`,
          `tasks`.`data`,
          `votes`.`up`,
          `votes`.`down`
     FROM `tasks`
LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT `item`,
                      SUM(`up`) AS `up`,
                      SUM(`down`) AS `down`
                 FROM `votes`
             GROUP BY `item`
          ) AS `votes`
       ON `votes`.`item` = `tasks`.`id`
    WHERE `tasks`.`user` = 1
```

Comment: Indeed it doesn't work, here's the error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'r.id' in 'where clause'`, looks like the line `WHERE t.item = r.id`. And as far as my understanding goes, it's the problem with `r` set after the JOIN... correct me if I'm wrong, just trying to learn from all this too.

Comment: Well, since you had the first perfectly working answer, I'm granting the credit to you, thanks for your effort! And gotta say, my mind is much clearer about these JOINs now.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see I would code something like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.user, t.data, ifnull(u.total, 0) as up, ifnull(d.total, 0) as down
FROM
    tasks AS t LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT item, SUM(up) AS total FROM votes GROUP BY item
    ) AS u ON t.id = u.item LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT item, SUM(down) AS total FROM votes GROUP BY item
    ) AS d ON t.id = u.item
WHERE t.user = 1;
```

Then for showing both totals in a single row you can try:

```
SELECT t.id, t.user, t.data,
    ifnull((SELECT SUM(up) FROM votes GROUP BY item WHERE item = t.id), 0) AS up,
    ifnull((SELECT SUM(down) FROM votes GROUP BY item WHERE item = t.id), 0) AS down
FROM tasks AS t
WHERE t.user = 1;
```

Or try this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.user, t.data, IFNULL(tt.up, 0) AS up, IFNULL(tt.down, 0) AS down
FROM
    tasks AS t LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT item, SUM(up) AS up, SUM(down) AS down
        FROM votes
        GROUP BY item
    ) AS tt ON t.id = tt.item
WHERE t.user = 1
```

Comment: This is closer to what I'm looking for, but instead of showing one row from *tasks* it shows duplicate entry. One for up votes, one for down votes.

Comment: Well... I found out the solution for double entry (missing GROUP BY), but it provides incorrect results for `down` votes.